# Delete operation in a binary search tree not working correctly

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement the deletion function in a binary search tree. I know that the three steps are:

1. Identifying the node to be deleted and the deepest node.
2. Replacing its data with the data of the deepest node.
3. Deleting the deepest node.

I tried to implement it like that, but the deletion is not working

What is wrong with my attempt and how can I fix it?

```
TREE *delete(TREE *t,int d) {
    TREE *temp=NULL;
    if(t==NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(d>t->data)
        return delete(t->right,d);
    else if(d<t->data)
        return delete(t->left,d);
    else {
        if(t->right && t->left) {
            temp=min(t->right);
            t->data=temp->data;
            return delete(t->right,t->data);
        }
        else {
            temp=t;
            if(t->left==NULL)
                t=t->right;
            else if(t->right==NULL)
                t=t->left;
            free(temp);
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: If I set the link null then it shows garbage value

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call `delete` recursively, you *return* its return value. This is not correct.

When `delete` is called with first argument `t->right`, then the returned node is what `t->right` should become. So this value must be *assigned* to `t->right`. And after that assignment, `t` should be returned.

There are three lines in your code where you make a recursive call. They should all be modified as indicated above. And the `return t` statement should be moved out of the `else` block, so that it is executed for all relevant cases.

```
TREE *delete(TREE *t, int d) {
    TREE *temp = NULL;
    if (t == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if (d > t->data)
        t->right = delete(t->right, d); // Assign the return value
    else if (d < t->data)
        t->left = delete(t->left, d); // ...
    else {
        if (t->right && t->left) {
            temp = min(t->right);
            t->data = temp->data;
            t->right = delete(t->right, t->data); // ...
        }
        else {
            temp = t;
            if (t->left == NULL)
                t = t->right;
            else // No need to have an IF here.
                t = t->left;
            free(temp);
        }
    }
    return t; // Moved here
}
```